# Trying to create a record for each item in an order with SQLite Database and Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I believe that I need to to expand the sql statement as the current one I have:

```
SELECT OrderID FROM Orders WHERE UserID = (?)
```

is likely to cause problems in the future when there are users with multiple orders. Is there a way that I can select and use the autoincrementing orderID in my orders table in combination?

For reference, my DB looks like this:
[image: Database]

And the python I currently have is like this however I feel that it may have to be rewritten entirely.

`results[0][0]` is the ID of the current user from the Users table

```
  elif userinput == "5":
            basket = []
            print(pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM Products', conn))

            shopping = True
            while shopping:

                itemToAdd = input("Please enter the ID of the item to add to the basket: ")
                basket.append(itemToAdd)
                print(basket)
                continueShop = input("Continue shopping?(y/n): ")
                if continueShop == "n":
                    conn.execute("INSERT INTO Orders (UserID) VALUES (?)", (results[0][0],))
                    conn.commit()
                    counter = 0
                    for items in basket:
                        createOrderItems = "INSERT INTO OrderItems (OrderID, ProductID) VALUES (?,?)"
                        currentOrder = ("SELECT OrderID FROM Orders WHERE UserID = (?) ", (results[0][0]))
                        conn.execute(createOrderItems, (currentOrder[0], basket[counter]))
                        counter = +1
                        conn.commit()
```

Because the database is built using the DB Browser application, I really have no clue how to access the parts of it that I need to ensure I am selecting the right record. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Also, since the primary key of each table is autoincrementing I need a way to select only the record that was created just now using

```
   conn.execute("INSERT INTO Orders (UserID) VALUES (?)",
```

However, I cannot think of a way to do so even though the record is unique in the orders table, as there is no way of knowing which order is the one that needs to be looked at as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`lastrowid` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.lastrowid) of the cursor object to find the id of the inserted order. Then use a compound WHERE in the select statement (ie WHERE userid = something and orderid = something_else).